# What is the CSS-Selector "code" in React 'npm start' project file 'index.css' for?

Tags: css, reactjs

Does anyone knows what this selector is for? I tried to apllied rules to find out (smth like color: red; and so on...), but i seems it doenst change anything and i cant find something in the docs about it.

[Code related to question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeswV.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the `<code>` html tag. It will apply given style properties to this element.
Check W3C docu:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_code.asp

Answer (score 0):

The HTML `code` element is used to represent code in browsers. It usually has a monospace font and some other stylings. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/code

For example:

```html
<p>Did you know you can use a <code>&lt;span&gt;</code> element to style arbitrary text?</p>
```